# How to get "npm run configure" work without having an error?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

So I'm working on a program and I can't get it to work. I did the SQL configuration, I changed the package.json and I also linked everything. Once I write "npm run configure" in my terminal, I get an error and I can't find the solution for 3 days.

I'm using PostgreSQL for the SQL and I created everything to make it work but even by changing the SQL, the path or the configuration, nothing seems to work.

Once I type "npm run configure" I get this error message:

> backend@1.0.0 configure C:\Users\Christofer\Desktop\Document\developpement web\FullStack-Mern-DragonStack\backEnd
>   ./bin/configure_db.sh
>
> '.' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
>   ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 configure: `./bin/configure_db.sh`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 configure script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Christofer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-05T09_33_02_208Z-debug.log

I should run the script I did in configure_db.sh and let me create a new table

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Windows.

Add "sh" to the configure script, like this.

"configure": "sh ./bin/configure_db.sh"

Install Git Bash and now try to execute with "npm run configure" inside Git Bash cmd.